# Handling producer thread when no consumers are ready

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, producer-consumer

Suggestions on patterns for handling the following scenario:

A single thread that dispatches events to consumers. There is a 1:1 between each event and a consumer  (each event is dispatched to a single consumer based on event/consumer id match).

Consumers process events at varying speeds and can consume events in configurable batch sizes (e.g. a consumer could consume 20 events at a time).

The producer thread should always be able to dispatch events to consumers that are capable of consuming. Each consumer maintains a queue of events it has consumed (possibly in batch) and processes these on its own thread, so the hand-off from producer to consumer is asynchronous.

If no consumers can consume at any point in time, what should happen to the dispatch thread?

- `yield()` it
- `wait()` & force consumers to call `notify()` on it
- `sleep()` for a fixed time period
- spin

Any reason to prefer one over the other?

Some pros & cons:

- yield is simple
- forcing consumers to call notify adds complexity
- sleep for a fixed time would suit for non time sensitive requirements
- spinning eats up a CPU, unnecessary unless we need as fast as possible event delivery

Any other considerations?

Comment: Just to be totally clear: you're talking about direct handoff from the dispatcher to the consumers, with no event queues in between?

Comment: Sorry, was not clear. The hand off from dispatcher to consumer is asynchronous, each consumer maintains it's own event queue.

Comment: Complete sentences would help to understand the scenario.  Also, if one consumer can consume multiple events, that is not "1:1".

Comment: Consumers can consume events in batch  and only one consumer can consume any one event (the dispatch thread looks up the correct consumer for each event based on an ID)

Comment: How are the events generated? Is there a method to wait for the next event to be generated? If there is all you need to do is to have a loop on the producer thread that calls this method and dispatches each event to the correct consumer as the events are generated. This makes sure that the consumers always get fed an event as soon as it arrives and since the producer thread is waiting the remainder of the time, that there is no unnecessary CPU load.

Comment: I can generate events as fast as consumers can consume them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a)  You could choose `yield` but depending on how good the environment is, this could essentially become a no-op. So this would essentially have the same result as spinning.

b) Sleep is an easy choice but then you should come up with how long to sleep.  Doing `sleep(0)` also will not help as it will be same as doing (a)

The force of notification is more complicated but you have complete control of your flow.

Comment: Do you mean use the blocking queue as the event handoff queue between producer and consumer? If there are multiple consumers (each on their own thread) and a single producer thread then will this not cause the producer to sometimes block waiting on a consumer when it could potentially be dispatching a different event to another consumer?

Comment: @Joel:I see what you mean.I think that if you have time you should go for notification

Answer (score 4):

Another way you should consider would be writing it to a `BlockingQueue`.  Let the queue manage requests sent without listeners.

Even better: write a `Broker` that owns a `BlockingQueue` and maintains a `List` of `Consumers`.  Have the `Broker` notify the `List` of `Consumers` when a `Producer` sends a new `Event`.

I'd use the `PropertyChangeListener` and `EventObject` built into Java Beans since JDK 1.0 to do this in memory.

Comment: If I have a single producer thread I don't want it to block on one consumer when others could potentially consume

Comment: The producer will only block when the `BlockingQueue` is full (and even then, it depends on the method you use to insert elements into the queue). If some consumers will process batches of events, you should use either a LinkedBlockingQueue or an ArrayBlockingQueue (the other option would be a SynchronousQueue, but this is only useful if you want to send exactly one event at a time, and block the producer unless there's a consumer ready, listening).

Comment: Have edited question to reflect the fact that each consumer has it's own thread and queue of events it has been handed.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [JMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service). JMS is designed to handle exactly this kind of use case.

A full scale JMS installation might be overkill in your scenario – you don't provide enough information.